# How to combine vectors of different length in a cell array into matrix in SCILAB?

Tags: arrays, vector, cell, scilab, combiners

Is there any function in SCILAB that looks like
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33453-catpad
?

I have a lot of *.csv with wind values of several cities in a region that I should study. But when I try to put the wind values for each column of a new variable, it returns the error 15 "Submatrix incorrectly defined". Is possible to put the values together in a single array or I must use list instead of array? The wind values are in the 4° column of the "data" variable:

```
function A1 = csvread_Folder()

folder_name=uigetdir();
files=dir(fullfile(folder_name,'*.csv'));
header = 16;

for i=1:length(files)
    data = csvRead(files.name(i),';',[],'double',[],[],[],header);
    A1(:,i) = data(:,4);
end    
endfunction
```

Comment: I managed to run the code by declaring the variable A1 before the for loop.

Comment: But what did you do about the different length? Shorter vectors will be filled up with zeros, right?